# How to select faces around sharp edges and subdivide by using Geometry Nodes?

Tags: geometry-nodes

I am trying to test Geometry Nodes in Blender 3.5.

I have two different cylinders and apply union operation with Mesh Boolean node as follows:

[image]

The geometry nodes for this operation are as follows:

[image]

What I want to do is to select faces around sharp edges including the juncture of the two cylinders and apply subdivision to get more faces around sharp edges.

I tried to figure out what kind of node do the work but in vain.
Is it not possible yet in Blender 3.5 to do what I am trying to do?

[image]

Comment: if you provide blend file you would attract more lazy people (like me) to help you because we don't have to recreate everything on our own

Comment: You should look into the "Intersecting Edges" output of the Mesh Boolean node

Comment: @Chris How can I upload blend file. I could not see upload button for blend file.

Comment: @Chris I uploaded a blend file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it like this...but (!) it doesn't make a nice topology which i think you wanna have...

[image]

[image]

Hint:

this works only, if you change the settings of one cylinder like this:

[image]

the separated geometry (from intersecting) looks like this:

[image]

or like this if you increase the threshold:

[image]

I have no clue whether it is a bug, if the vertices and edges overlap exactly in mesh boolean...because the result of the intersecting edges is just nothing.

Comment: Thank you so much. As you said, it would be better if the refined topology develops in a concentric way, though. Anyway I can now figure out a little how Geometry Nodes work. It's somewhat odd it works only when cylinder segment size is something other than 32 and 12. Is it kind of bug?

Comment: i assume, but i am not sure.